# why i am getting error on first nextjs steps

Tags: node.js, next.js

So, i'm just following the guide that the guys is nextjs.org have put in place which seem quite good. https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/getting-started/setup

When i get to the point i run [after just a couple basic steps]

```
npm run dev
```

i get immediately a nasty error:

```
hello-next npm run dev

> hello-next@1.0.0 dev /Users/myuser/Projects/ssr/hello-next
> next

/Users/myuser/Projects/ssr/hello-next/node_modules/hard-source-    webpack-plugin/index.js:106
}
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myuser/Projects/ssr/hello-next/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack.js:64:55)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! hello-next@1.0.0 dev: `next`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the hello-next@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/myuser/.npm/_logs/2018-09-27T22_05_37_582Z-debug.log
```

This has to be something in my system, but i wonder what. I tried it in my laptop and it also happens there.

I went to this file and looks super normal, located in node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin/index.js:

```
function contextNormalLoaders(compiler, loaders) {
  return loaders.map(loader =>
    Object.assign({}, loader, {
      loader: contextNormalPath(compiler, loader.loader),
    }),
  );
}
```

I've looked around to see if anyone had had this error, and found nothing like this. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by someone else after i posted it in the nextjs github page. I basically had an old node version.

Reference: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/5325